# Hibernate format date in order by

Tags: hibernate

In my datebase, I have defined a timestamp field named "creation_date".
What I'm trying to do is to have a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date(creation_date) desc
```

My code is defined as it is (relevant parts only) :

```
Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(TableClass.class);
crit.addOrder(Order.desc("date(creationDate)");
return crit.list();
```

but this results in an Hibernate exception ...

Thanks for any help

EDIT : 
creation_date holds "2015-08-17 15:01:37" but I want to order by DATE(creation_date) to only keep "2015-08-17"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate criteria API doesn't know all SQL functions of underlying DB.
You have to write custom ordering class extending hibernate org.hibernate.criterion.Order.class. Check [this](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/) for example.

(OR) simpler you can use HQL in your case instead of Criteria API like this

```
Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from TableClass order by date(creationDate) desc ");
return query.list();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've extended Order class and this works awesome !